# No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am playing around with GAN for image tasks, but got this error in my generator

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "BannerGenerate.py", line 208, in 
    SeparateGANTrainer(config, g_period=6).train()

File "/root/tensorflow_tangchuanxin/GAN/GAN.py", line 118, in **init**
    model.g_loss, var_list=model.g_vars, name='g_min')

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 350, in minimize
    ([str(v) for _, v in grads_and_vars], loss))

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables [""...... "", ""] and loss Tensor("g_loss:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).

Here is part of my code. I cannot' figure out why there is no connection on the graph.

```
def generator(self, img, img1):
    assert img is not None
    assert img1 is not None
    tmp_img = tf.concat([img,img1],axis=0)
    l = self.Resnet101(tmp_img)
    l = LinearWrap.tensor(l)
    l, l1 = tf.split(l, 2, axis=0)
    l = tf.concat([l,l1],3)
    with argscope([Conv2D, GlobalAvgPooling, InstanceNorm], data_format='NHWC'):
        x1 = Conv2D('conv_x', l, 1, kernel_shape=1, nl=tf.sigmoid, stride=1)
        x1 = GlobalAvgPooling('global_avg_pooling1', x1)
        y1 = Conv2D('conv_y', l, 1, kernel_shape=1, nl=tf.sigmoid, stride=1)
        y1 = GlobalAvgPooling('global_avg_pooling2', y1)
        height = Conv2D('conv_height', l, 1, kernel_shape=1, nl=tf.sigmoid, stride=1)
        height = GlobalAvgPooling('global_avg_pooling3', height)
        width = Conv2D('conv_width', l, 1, kernel_shape=1, nl=tf.sigmoid, stride=1)
        width = GlobalAvgPooling('global_avg_pooling4', width)
    #imgs_gen = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img, pos, tf.range(BATCH), tf.constant([HEIGHT,WIDTH]))
    #x1, y1, height, width = tf.split(pos, 4, axis=1)
    x1 = tf.cast(x1 * tf.constant(HEIGHT-1, shape=[BATCH,1], dtype=tf.float32), tf.int32)
    y1 = tf.cast(y1 * tf.constant(WIDTH-1, shape=[BATCH,1], dtype=tf.float32), tf.int32)
    height = tf.cast(height * tf.constant(HEIGHT-1, shape=[BATCH,1], dtype=tf.float32), tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(width * tf.constant(WIDTH-1, shape=[BATCH,1], dtype=tf.float32), tf.int32)
    box_x = tf.split(x1, BATCH, axis=0)
    box_y = tf.split(y1, BATCH ,axis=0)
    box_h = tf.split(height, BATCH, axis=0)
    box_w = tf.split(width, BATCH, axis=0)
    img = tf.split(img, BATCH, axis=0)
    img1 = tf.split(img1, BATCH, axis=0)
    imgs_gen = []
    for i in range(BATCH):
        x = tf.to_int32(tf.squeeze(box_x[i]))
        y = tf.to_int32(tf.squeeze(box_y[i]))
        h = tf.to_int32(tf.squeeze(box_h[i]))
        w = tf.to_int32(tf.squeeze(box_w[i]))
        img1[i] = tf.image.resize_bilinear(img1[i], [h, w])
        img1[i] = tf.image.resize_bilinear(img1[i], [HEIGHT, WIDTH])
        mask = tf.ones_like(img1[i])
        zero_pad = tf.constant([[0,0]])
        h_pad = tf.concat([tf.reshape(tf.maximum(x-1,0),[1,1]), tf.reshape(HEIGHT-x-h,[1,1])], axis=1)
        w_pad = tf.concat([tf.reshape(tf.maximum(y-1,0),[1,1]), tf.reshape(WIDTH-y-w,[1,1])], axis=1)
        paddings = tf.concat([zero_pad, h_pad, w_pad, zero_pad], axis=0)
        img1[i] = tf.pad(img1[i], paddings)
        img1[i] = tf.reshape(img1[i],[1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3])
        mask = tf.pad(mask, paddings)
        img1[i] = img1[i] + img[i] - img[i] * mask
        imgs_gen.append(img1[i])
    imgs_gen = tf.concat(imgs_gen, axis=0)

    return imgs_gen
```

Comment: Post the full traceback of the error, like this we don't even know which line is casing the error in the first place

Comment: Which library are you using for Conv2D and others. As far as I know neither TF nor Keras have "nl" keyword argument. Also, with these libraries, Conv2D returns you a layer, not a tensor, you can't multiply a layer by a tensor like you do in `height = tf.cast(height * tf.constant(...` Please provide more information for anyone to reasonably help you.

Comment: tensorpack(http://tensorpack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/models.html #tensorpack.models.Conv2D) and Conv2D returns a tensor. @iga

Comment: I already updated the traceback.@GPhilo